# USSD respons fails in flutter : messege PlatformException(ussd_plugin_ussd_response_failed, USSD_RETURN_FAILURE, null)

Tags: android, flutter, ussd, sim-card

I am trying to make silent USSD request,  I am using Ussd_Serivece & Sim_Service package for this in flutter.

any time I try to make a request it throws this exception: (error! Code: ussd_plugin_ussd_response_failed -  messege PlatformException(ussd_plugin_ussd_response_failed, USSD_RETURN_FAILURE, null)).

here is a code of my function:

```
    makeRequest() async {
  String code = '*221#';
  SimData data = await SimService.getSimData;
  print(data.activeSubscriptionInfoCount);
  print(code);

  try {
    String ussdRespMessege = await UssdService.makeRequest(
        data.cards.first.subscriptionId, '211#');
    print('Succes! messege: $ussdRespMessege');
  } catch (e) {
    print('error! Code: ${e.code} -  messege $e');
  }
}
```

I already handled permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/ussd_service) author here.
It looks like the second parameter than you are passing to `makeRequest` is missing a `*`, so it is expected that you are getting an error.
Try to replace it with

```dart
String ussdRespMessege = await UssdService.makeRequest(
        data.cards.first.subscriptionId, "*211#");
```

and it should work fine